# Is $\mathbb{Z}_2$ a subspace of $\mathbb{Z}_5 \times \mathbb{Z}_5$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The title is an example of what I'm trying to understand. I know formally what a subspace of a vector space is, but I'm not certain about this specific example:

Let $V = \mathbb{Z}_5 \times \mathbb{Z}_5$ be a vector space. Now, is $\mathbb{Z}_2$ a subspace of $V$ or does a subspace need to be in the form of $X \times X$, for instance, $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you verified the definition of a subspace?

Comment: How is $\mathbb{Z}_2$ even a subset of $V$?!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, by $\mathbb{Z}_p$ you mean the field with $p$ elements.

So, $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is not a subspace of your vector space. In fact, it is not even a subset.

As for your other question : no, a subspace is not necessarily of the form $X \times X$.
For instance, the diagonal in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a subspace. Actually, any line that goes through the origin is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$.
In your example $V$, the diagonal is also a subspace.